# Equivalent conditions for a real function to have antiderivates

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Lebesgue theorem says that a bounded function  $f$ is Riemann  Integerable if and only if $f$ continuous  almost everywhere.

Unfortunately,  we know a function  has antiderivative has no relation to Riemann  Integerable.

> **Q.**  Is there  some  nice equivalent condition to the fact that a real function has antiderivates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various characterizations of real functions which have antiderivatives. See, for example, Theorem 4 in M. W. Botsko: Exactly which bounded Darboux functions are derivatives?, Amer. Math. Monthly 114 (2007), 242-246.